# PHP sessions with shopping cart

Tags: php, session

I am modifying a simple shopping cart to learn. My problem is with session arrays. I have an index page where product page is required by using require statement to show.

I also require `cart.php` (where cart summary is located). When  I add a product for the first time, it does not show on required `cart.php`. When I add another product, it shows the recent one but in actual `cart.php`, it shows two items are in the cart.

Does anyone have an idea where I am going wrong? Here is what I have:

```php
<div id="leftColumn">
    <?php require("cart.php"); ?>
    <div id="rightColumn">
        <?php require($page . ".php"); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: <div id="leftColumn">
 <?php require("cart.php"); ?>
  <div id="rightColumn">
        <?php require($page . ".php"); ?>
      </div>

Comment: Hi! In order to hep you we are going to need some code, please edit your question to include some code and any error messages you might have.

Comment: Title is changed & removed array tags.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to read some [documentations](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) first before asking questions. Please try implementing it first and show us the code you're currently having problems with.

example in W3Schools:

```
<?php

// Start the session
session_start();

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
// Set session variables
$_SESSION["favcolor"] = "green";
$_SESSION["favanimal"] = "cat";
echo "Session variables are set.";
?>

</body>
</html>
```